# Jquery Ajax not working with All Internet Explorer (IE)

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I wrote a small code Jquery Ajax to call a select box in a PHP page in the page at the click of a select option:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajax ({  
        cache:false,
        type: 'get',
    });  

    var ajax_load = "<img src='img/loading.gif' class='loading-comuni' alt='loading...' />";  
    var alessandria =  "comuni/alessandria.php"; 

    jQuery(".alessandria").click(function(){  
        jQuery("#piemonte-comuni").html(ajax_load).load(alessandria);  
    }); 
});
```

The code works properly with all web browsers (I click in and out of the div select in the 'ID) but does not work on all versions of Internet Explorer. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which versions of IE don't work? Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: `type: 'get',` remove the comma to win.

Comment: Here is the script of http://jsfiddle.net/all2aller/tLAC9/2/ not only works on IE

Answer (score 0):

Older IE versions don't support extra comma in object declaration:

```
jQuery.ajax ({  
        cache:false,
        type: 'get'//, << extra comma here, remove it
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried to remove the comma but does not work on IE always the same.

Comment: Of course you have clear your browser cache? Which version of IE? You still didn't answer this simple question

Comment: BTW, which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I use IE 10 but I also tried on IE 8 and IE 9 with simulators as browserstack.com. Jquery 1.9.1.